# Is there a prettier login screen for Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: gnome, login-screen, 18.10, gdm

Not sure why but my Ubuntu 18.10 has installed with a rather visually ugly login screen.

I’ve seen people with older versions have nicer login pages, am I missing anything? Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That looks to me like a standard `gdm3` greeter screen. Not showing a picture for your account is supposed to be safer (ie. revealing less about the account you are logging into).  You could always replace gdm with another greeter, but it does provide some configuration "such as changing the logo icon, display background, and GTK theme" which the following may help - https://wiki.debian.org/GDM

Answer (score 0):

That looks to me like a standard `gdm3` greeter screen. Not showing a picture for your account is supposed to be safer (*ie. revealing less about the account you are logging into*).

You could always replace gdm with another greeter, (older Ubuntu used `lightdm`) but `gdm3` does provide some configuration

> such as changing the logo icon, display background, and GTK theme

for which the following wiki may help https://wiki.debian.org/GDM otherwise a search engine scan provided me many howto's.
(I didn't see a Ubuntu wiki page for gdm)